# SQL pivot/Unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, unpivot

Really hoping someone can help me out here, I have a table structured as below:

The query to retrieve this data is:

```
SELECT

[Pattern Number]
,Sunday
,Monday
,Tuesday
,Wednesday
,Thursday
,Friday
,Saturday

FROM Access.Pattern_Details
WHERE [Pattern Number] = 4
```

```
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
| Pattern Number | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
|              4 |      0 |      1 |       1 |         1 |        1 |      1 |        0 |
+----------------+--------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+
```

That I'd like to get looking like this:

```
+----------------+------------+-----------+
| Pattern Number | WorkingDay |    Day    |
+----------------+------------+-----------+
|              4 |          0 | Sunday    |
|              4 |          1 | Monday    |
|              4 |          1 | Tuesday   |
|              4 |          1 | Wednesday |
|              4 |          1 | Thursday  |
|              4 |          1 | Friday    |
|              4 |          0 | Saturday  |
+----------------+------------+-----------+
```

I've tried `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` which feels like the right direction to go in, but am really struggling with how to get the result :(

Comment: Hi Cordy, include the query you tried in your question please.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? The answer is vendor-dependent.

Comment: UNION ALL is a simple way.

Comment: If you've tried something and had a problem, show that something and describe that problem. "really struggling with how to get the result" is not a description readers can do anything with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would recommend `cross apply` and `values()`:

```
select pd.[Pattern Number], x.*
from Access.Pattern_Details pd
cross apply (values 
    ('Sunday',    Sunday), 
    ('Monday',    Monday),
    ('Tuesday',   Tuesday),
    ('Wednesday', Wednesday),
    ('Thursday',  Thursday),
    ('Friday',    Friday),
    ('Saturday',  Saturday)
) x(day, workingDay)
where pd.[Pattern Number] = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT [Pattern Number], [Working Day], [Day] 
FROM
(
  SELECT 4 [Pattern Number], 0 Sunday, 1 Monday, 1 Tuesday, 1 Wednesday, 1 Thursday, 1 Friday, 0 Saturday
) pvt
UNPIVOT([Working Day] FOR [Day] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])) unpvt
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=427937e0c241d68621ffe0e680aedce3)

`UNPIVOT` is very well documented and explained. See: [Using Pivot and Unpivot - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)